# New Flycheck syntax checker: Errors missing

Tags: flycheck

I am attempting add an additional `Flycheck` syntax checker for `nxml-mode`, however errors/warnings are not showing up even though the linter, `igor`, is reporting errors/warnings.

Here is the syntax checker definition.

```
(flycheck-define-checker igor
  "FreeBSD Documentation Project sanity checker.

See URLs http://www.freebsd.org/docproj/ and 
http://www.freshports.org/textproc/igor/."
  :command ("igor" "-X" source-original)
  :standard-input t
  :error-parser flycheck-parse-checkstyle
  :modes (nxml-mode))
```

I made the new definition available for automatic selection.

```
(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'igor 'append)
```

When the major mode is `nxml-mode`, I can run `flycheck-verify-setup` to verify that `igor` is listed as a checker.

```
Syntax checkers for buffer chapter.xml in nxml-mode:

  xml-xmlstarlet
    - predicate:  t
    - executable: Found at /usr/local/bin/xml

  xml-xmllint
    - predicate:  t
    - executable: Found at /usr/local/bin/xmllint

  igor
    - predicate:  t
    - executable: Found at /usr/local/bin/igor

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.
```

If I run `flycheck-compile` and chose `igor`, I see errors/warnings.

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/scm/nm/freebsd-docs.svn/doc/head/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/editor-config/" -*-
Compilation started at Wed Jul 13 15:12:14

igor -X /home/jrm/scm/nm/freebsd-docs.svn/doc/head/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/editor-config/chapter.xml
<file name="/home/jrm/scm/nm/freebsd-docs.svn/doc/head/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/editor-config/chapter.xml">
  <error line="49" column="1" severity="warning" message="spelling" source="igor" />
  <error line="56" column="1" severity="warning" message="wrap long line" source="igor" />
  <error line="112" column="1" severity="warning" message="bad tag indent" source="igor" />
  <error line="114" column="1" severity="warning" message="bad tag indent" source="igor" />
  <error line="114" column="1" severity="warning" message="wrap long line" source="igor" />
  <error line="115" column="1" severity="warning" message="bad tag indent" source="igor" />
  <error line="115" column="1" severity="warning" message="wrap long line" source="igor" />
  <error line="119" column="1" severity="warning" message="wrap long line" source="igor" />
  <error line="120" column="1" severity="warning" message="blank line with whitespace" source="igor" />
</file>

Compilation finished at Wed Jul 13 15:12:15
```

I can get basic error checking using `:error-patterns` instead of `:error-parser` in the definition, so the problem may be related to parsing the checkstyle XML output.

I am running the sixth pretest for the soon-to-be-released as Emacs 25.1.  What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know that the syntax checker doesn't report any errors?  What happens when you explicitly select it with C-c ! s?

Comment: Using `C-c ! n` gives "No more Flycheck errors" even after I insert errors that I know will trigger igor.  These errors are reported when I do `C-c ! C-c` and select igor.  Explicitly selecting igor with `C-c ! s` makes no difference.

Comment: Does removing :standard-input t from the definition make any difference?

Comment: No.  I've tried adding/removing all combinations of `:standard-input t`  `:command ("igor" "-X" source)` `:command ("igor" "-X" source-inplace)`.  The only thing that does work is when I use `:error-patterns...` instead of `:error-parser ...`.

Comment: How would you replace :error-parser? Can you add a working definition to your question?

Comment: Oh, it occurred to me that the XML you've shown isn't in Checkstyle format, so naturally the checkstyle parser won't find any errors.  Why did you even use it in the first place?  You'll need a custom error order for this XML format.

Comment: When I change the definition to `(flycheck-define-checker igor
  "FreeBSD Documentation Project sanity checker.

See URL http://www.freebsd.org/docproj/."
  :command ("igor" "-z" source-original)
  :standard-input t
  :error-patterns
  ((error line-start (file-name) ":" line ":" (message) line-end))
  :modes (nxml-mode))` it works, but only after I select it explicitly with `C-c ! s`.

Comment: Ah, Ok.  I was thrown off because the `igor` man page says `-X        Produce Checkstyle XML output.`

Comment: Oh this is wrong; please report this to the developers of the tool.  Notably the output is missing the proper root node, and there may be further differences (I didn't take a closer look).

Comment: Surrounding igor's output with `<checkstyle version="7.0">` and `</checkstyle>` works.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've found out in our discussion in the comments, contrary to its manpage `igor` does not create proper Checkstyle XML.  The XML document lacks the `checkstyle` root tag.

Flycheck's `flycheck-parse-checkstyle` parser expects this root tag and thus fails to parse Igor's output.  It simply doesn't find the tags it's looking for and can't parse any errors from the XML document.

You need to write a custom error parser.  As you've already found out that wrapping the `checkstyle` tag around the output is sufficient, I'd just do exactly that:

```
(defun flycheck-parse-igor (output checker buffer)
  (flycheck-parse-checkstyle (concat "<checkstyle version=\"7.0\">"
                                     output
                                     "</checkstyle>")
                             checker buffer))
```

If you use this function as `:error-parser` you should see errors from `igor` in the buffer.

---

Please also take the time to report this issue to the developers of `igor` and ask them to either add the `checkstyle` tag to their output or change the manpage.

Comment: I have submitted a patch to the Igor developer.  Thanks again.